# Determining slow nodes on a cluster

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

I have the following problem I need help solving.

I am running jobs on a cluster that is yielding different performance times every time. I suspect that some of the nodes may not be running optimally.

This cluster has 60 nodes. Each job uses 12 nodes. And for each job I know

- The nodes that were used
- How long a specific job took (specifically how long a inverting a matrix takes), my figure of merit

I currently have run 20 jobs. A lot of the nodes used overlap with some variation. I would like to find a way to assign a probability that nodeA is the one that is not running optimal.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you assign particular nodes when the job runs? If yes, you can fix 11 nodes and then run the same job 49 times hoping that you find the slow node. Of course, the slow node(s) may be part of the original selection but either way, you should be able to reduce the number of suspects.

Comment: In principle we can, but the time it would take for these particular nodes to be available would be unreasonably long. To remain the most productive, I figured it would be best to maximize my through-put, gather as much data as possible, and figure out which nodes are more than likely problematic. 

If these nodes are identified, I can ask for a reservation of the "good" nodes and give the IT people some reasonable justification for why I think certain nodes are not that efficient.